# CSS display:table images in cells don't match height

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Consider this sample. It's a very simple CSS table, with one row, and three nearly identical cells, each containing a 1000x1000px black square, `max-width: 100%`, but the length of the text in the cells varies from cell to cell.

```css
.table {
 display: table;
}

.row {
 display: table-row;
}

.cell {
 display: table-cell;
 max-width: 500px;
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
}

.title {
 font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
 <div class='row'>
  <div class='cell'>
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="black 1000x1000px square" />
   <div class='title'>1234567890 12345 67890</div>
  </div>
  <div class='cell'>
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="black 1000x1000px square" />
   <div class='title'>12345 67890</div>
  </div>
  <div class='cell'>
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="black 1000x1000px square" />
   <div class='title'>12 34567</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Run the snippet and resize the browser window such that some of the text needs to wrap to the next line. (A viewport less than ~800px wide should suffice.)

Actual: The first cell remains large while the second and third cells shrink in size.

[image: first cell big, later cells smaller]

Expected: I expected (and desired) for all of the images to be the same size in this table.

Why is this happening? How can I achieve the effect I expected?

Comment: Basically what's happening is that the table is being laid out based on how much space the text takes up, then after the space is calculated, the browser fits the images within that space. Someone should be able to explain this in more detail in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In table, `max-width` will not work in all cases, even `width` could change depending on the size of content inside. In your example, if you remove or put exactly the same text in `<div class='title'>` in each cell, then it will distribute the cells equally, since all has exactly the same amount content length.

If you want to maintain equal width cell in any case, you can apply:

```
.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

What's going to happen is browser will render the table layout even before the data gets loaded. It won't care what's inside, and always maintain equal width cells, unless you manually set CSS `width`, or use `<col>` or `<td width="nn">` in the markup.

If you want the table width to grow beyond the container if needed (in your example that would be body viewport). You can apply:

```
.table {
  display: inline-table;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;` to `.table`. Might also want to add `word-break: break-all;` to `.title` as well.

```css
.table {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   table-layout: fixed;
}

.row {
 display: table-row;
}

.cell {
 display: table-cell;
 max-width: 500px;
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
}

.title {
 font-size: 4em;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
 <div class='row'>
  <div class='cell'>
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="black 1000x1000px square" />
   <div class='title'>1234567890 12345 67890</div>
  </div>
  <div class='cell'>
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="black 1000x1000px square" />
   <div class='title'>12345 67890</div>
  </div>
  <div class='cell'>
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA+gAAAPoAQMAAAB3bUanAAABS2lUWHRYTUw6Y29tLmFkb2JlLnhtcAAAAAAAPD94cGFja2V0IGJlZ2luPSLvu78iIGlkPSJXNU0wTXBDZWhpSHpyZVN6TlRjemtjOWQiPz4KPHg6eG1wbWV0YSB4bWxuczp4PSJhZG9iZTpuczptZXRhLyIgeDp4bXB0az0iQWRvYmUgWE1QIENvcmUgNS42LWMxMzggNzkuMTU5ODI0LCAyMDE2LzA5LzE0LTAxOjA5OjAxICAgICAgICAiPgogPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4KICA8cmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIHJkZjphYm91dD0iIi8+CiA8L3JkZjpSREY+CjwveDp4bXBtZXRhPgo8P3hwYWNrZXQgZW5kPSJyIj8+IEmuOgAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAABc1JHQgCuzhzpAAAAA1BMVEUAAACnej3aAAAAkUlEQVR42u3BMQEAAADCoPVPbQo/oAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAvgbsPwABNAyb4wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="black 1000x1000px square" />
   <div class='title'>12 34567</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with git-e-up adding a defined width and table-layout: fixed; to .table will resolve the issue.

The issue is your cells do not have defined widths and neither do your images. The result is that the first cell is larger as it's being sized by the amount of text. As your image is set to max-width: 100% it's being defined by the size of it's parent table cell.

I'm confused by the markup though. If you're creating a table why not use HTML table elements? If you're just trying to create a three column layout then there are better methods. Flexbox for instance. This guide maybe of use https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I need to support pre-flexbox browsers.